# IMDPersitenceAgent running 100% CPU

Tags: macos, cpu

After a couple minutes of inactivity, often my fans start going on. I look at activity monitor and IMDPersistenceAgent is using 90-100% CPU. If I force quit it, it comes back.

I've attempted the following troubleshooting steps:

- Disabling handoff
- Signing in and out of iMessage
- Disabling contacts for all account
- Resetting NVRAM

[image]

I am forced to shut down my computer. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here are some logs:

```
error   17:38:41.720642-0400    IMDPersistenceAgent Main timer not started, can't start timing: post-processor
error   17:38:41.720674-0400    IMDPersistenceAgent Main timer not started, can't stop timing: post-processor
error   17:38:41.720710-0400    IMDPersistenceAgent Aleady stopped profiling
error   17:38:41.722263-0400    IMDPersistenceAgent Main timer not started, can't start timing: post-processor
error   17:38:41.722291-0400    IMDPersistenceAgent Main timer not started, can't stop timing: post-processor
error   17:38:41.722328-0400    IMDPersistenceAgent Aleady stopped profiling
```

Comment: I thought I have managed to fix this by signing out of iCloud (with removing everything related to iCloud), rebooting and signing in again. It worked for a few hours, until the first Time Machine backup...
Unfortunately see it again.

Comment: @lvs1974 Do you have many contact accounts with linked contacts? I seemed to have been able to solve it by consolidating all my contacts into a single account and disabling all the other ones for contacts.

Comment: I think it's a bug within macOS relating to linked contacts.